# How do you see what vertex groups are assigned to a bone?

Tags: bones, vertex-groups, rigify

I'm working with Rigify and parenting with automatic weights. This is generally quite good, but never perfect and needs some fine tuning. What I would like is to know what vertex groups are assigned to a bone to see if there's any mismatch. Is there any way to select a bone and see what vertex groups are associated with it?

It would be useful to know the other direction too, what vertices are assigned to what group, other than going through every group and pressing select or deselect.

Comment: You just need to select the vertex group that has the same name as the bone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mesh has a collection of Vertex groups that have the same name as the deforming bones in the armature.  To see what vertices are in a given Vertex group, in *Edit Mode*

- switch to vertex select mode to make it easier to see
- in the Object Data Properties panel click on the vertex group that has the same name as the bone you are interested in.
- click the select button.

To see what Vertex groups a given Vertex is assigned to, in *Edit Mode*

- switch to vertex select mode
- select the vertex you are interested in. This only works for single vertices at a time.
- In the side panel, select the *Item* tab.
- Under *Vertex Weights* there will be a list of each Vertex group the vertex is in:

[image: Side panel showing vertex weights]

This isn't a rigify example, so "Top" and "Bottom" are the names of bones in my armature.